# CSS заблокировать сайт и отобразить загрузку

Tags: html, css

Каким образом можно залочить страницу

[image]

ну чтобы не было возможности что либо сделать и отобразить по центру лоадер

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы показать `loader` добпвить класс `show` к `.loader-container`, чтобы спрятать добавть класс `hide`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.loader-container').addClass('show');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.loader-container').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.loader-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.loader-container.show {
  display:table-cell;
}
.loader-container.hide {
  display: none;
}
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="loader-container">
      <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery не заказывали...

Comment: в примерах bootstrap => jQuery

Comment: а без модалки никак?

Comment: @des1roer изменил

Comment: не вижу. мне бы на чистом css

Comment: как вы на чисто css собираетесь открывать, закрывать loader?

Comment: навесить класс - все залочено и загрузчик по центру. нет класса - нет лока

Comment: @des1roer надеюсь я вас правильно понял, поменял.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант решения

```
    .modal-mask {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9998;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        display: table;
        transition: opacity .3s ease;
    }

    .modal-wrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .loader {
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
        border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    /*-----------*/
    .loader {
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
        border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

     <div v-if="loader" class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <center> 
                <div class="loader"></div>   
            </center> 
        </div>             
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/des1roer/pen/YVvEaz